# Database Connection: Visual Studio 2010 and Microsoft Access 2007(OleDbException was unhandled)

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007, oledb

I am new in creating application using Visual Studio 2010 and Microsoft Access 2007. I tried connecting Visual Studio with MySQL as a database and it worked fine but when I changed it to MS Access I got errors stating that *OleDbException was unhandled* and *could not find the file*. The database file I created is in the same folder where the program is located

This is the printscreen of the error:
[image]

Comment: Did you check the basics? File exists, is not used by another process (that would be lame for a database...)?

Comment: Do you accidentally open this database connection elsewhere in your program?

Comment: @MPelletier: Only my system is using the database. I got a new error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is telling you what the problem is: "The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user".

Microsoft has a full explanation and solution [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823913).

Comment: I got a new problem here. It states that it couldn't find the database I created.

Comment: Are you sure that file actually exists? I usually copy the full file name out of the exception message and paste it into a windows explorer window nav bar to make sure there aren't any minor typos that I missed.

Comment: Is okay to have spaces in between the file name of a folder for the location of the database?

Comment: If you mean like c:\mydir\ mydb.mdb then No. If you mean like c:\my dir\mydb.mdb then yes.

Comment: It's like c:\my dir\mydb.mdb but still an error occured(Could not find the file).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you need to set your Build Settings to target x86 cpu for the JET.OleDb Provider to work. If you are targeting "ANy CPU" or x64, you will run into an exception.